# Extract domain name from given address Java RegEx

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I want output "xyz" instead of "www.xyz.com".
Mainly I asked this because I wanted to know how to extract something in between the pattern except the pattern itself.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("www[.].+[.]com");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("www.xyz.com");
        if(m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice question, too. And in case you reach 15 rep and you want to practice upvoting, I am around and glad to help ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ca use `\.(.*?)\.` which mean any thing between the two dots :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("www\\.(.*?)\\.com");
Matcher m = p.matcher("I saw a tree. tree was tall. now I will search tree on www.google.com .");
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

**output**

```
google
```

Comment: i don't get you @YashBhutoria !

Comment: In my case, I have to do this using a paragraph as an input. using this may cause trouble.
Suppose this input : "I saw a tree. tree was tall. now I will search tree on www.google.com ." @YCF_L

Comment: check my edit @YashBhutoria hope this can help you :)

Comment: what does that group one means ?(does this means second match ?) will this work in larger paragraphs ?

Comment: @YashBhutoria it mean that groupe between `www\\.` and `\\.com` yes i can work in large paragraphe like you already use in your example `I saw a tree. tree was tall. now I will search tree on www.google.com .`